# Given a ring R, is the set R[X] also a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let R be a ring.  Is R[X](the set of polynomials with coefficients in R) also a ring?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Well, the **set** isn't. But the set,  together with the natural addition and multiplication, is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$

EDIT: It appears my terseness has upset some people, so I will elaborate:

Yes it is.

EDIT: Okay okay fine. As usual, to see if something is a ring, you need to define addition and multiplication on the underlying set, and show that they satisfy all the properties required, which may depend on exactly what your definition of ring is (though in this case $R[X]$ is a ring in pretty much every definition of ring). Basically, the idea is to just show that the standard operations of adding and multiplying polynomials satisfies the necessary properties. I assume you have a textbook available in which you may look up the relevant definition of ring and see what those properties are.

EDIT: I dunno why I get downvotes but the even less helpful "What do you think?" comment by tomasz gets massively upvoted.